# Do mechanical waves also carry momentum as well as energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, waves

I have read that electromagnetic waves carry momentum because they carry energy, while energy is equivalent to mass. So they carry momentum. But this explanation is in the context of special relativity. I don't know whether mass energy equivalence is necessary for wave momentum. So I hope you can discuss in the contexts of both Newtonian or special relativity. A quantitative definition like the Maxwell stress tensor of electromagnetic wave is better.

Comment: This is an overly broad question, and it smells strongly of 'homework' - you show no background in the topic. If I told you to go use an elasticity tensor what would you do?

Comment: I know electromagnetic waves are not mechanical waves. I just took it for an example of quantitative expression of momentum of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: I have read that electromagnetic waves have momentum because electromagnetic waves have energy, while energy is equivalent to mass. So electromagnetic waves have momentum. But this explanation used the result of special relativity. I don't know whether it's necessary to wave momentum.

Comment: If you want to narrow it, just talk about the simplest scenario, the one dimensional linear wave governed by d'Alembert equation.

Comment: For physical particles,  you cannot have momentum without kinetic energy, and vice versa.  End of story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mechanical waves are those that need a specific medium for their propagation. Of course, the medium has to be physical. There are two types of mechanical waves: transverse and longitudinal. But, first of all, electromagnetic waves that show transverse property are not mechanical waves since they don't essentially need any medium for their propagation.

The so called "wave" is nothing but a disturbance occurred in a certain particle or a group of particles in a medium. A medium characterized by interacting particles transfer this disturbance which we call the "wave motion". Once you affect the equilibrium energy of the particle, the particle vibrate which makes the neighboring particles also vibrate as they all can be visualized as mutually connected by springs. So this disturbance you supplied to a particle is transferred from particle to particle throughout the medium. So a wave definitely carries some energy. A wave is oscillatory in nature. So it has an acceleration which means there is an associated rate of change in momentum of the oscillating particles. So, by giving an additional energy we are giving an additional momentum to the particle. So this momentum is also transferring along with the energy. Take an example of sound waves (longitudinal). It moves by pressurizing and depressurizing the particles in the medium along it's direction of propagation. One nice example with sound waves is that they could break your car glasses if you put inside a music box with all the glasses closed and playing it loudly; when the frequency of the wave hits the natural frequency of glass, resonance happen and the glass vibrate with maximum amplitude and breaks. Inside the car there is air. The particles of the air vibrate at the resonant frequency of the glass particles thereby exchanging energy. But air and glass particles are entirely two different medium. How they interacted. By collision. The particles in the air vibrates more rigorously and thus colliding the glass particles with maximum momentum. This momentum transfer is by which the glass particles gain energy. So they carry energy as well as momentum. So is the case of transverse waves.

But it is always preferable to talk about momentum density carried by a mechanical wave in the classical aspect rather than speaking about momentum. This may create confusions. For example when we speak about momentum of a wave the first thing that comes to our mind is the property of a moving body in the direction of motion. But take for example, a transverse wave. The particles of the medium vibrate perpendicular to the direction of propagation. This means that the momentum of the particles is perpendicular to the motion of the wave. So here in the wave aspect we are interested in momentum density.

Now, in terms of special relativity, the momentum associated by a wave is given by

Following the insight of Einstein that energy and mass are related by E = m$c^2$, the energy density $u_s$ is associated with a mass density $u_s$/$c^2$. Hence, there is a momentum density in the sound wave given by

$p_s$ = $u_s$$v_s$/$c^2$ = **S**/$c^2$

where c is the velocity of light,
$v_s$- velocity of sound wave
**S**- energy flux vector

Now, about the stress tensor.

Stress is a tensor of rank 2. Here is how it goes. Remember that the stress and force are related by

$Stress = Force × Area $

Force is a vector quantity. Area is also a vector quantity. So, for stress has two options as vectors can be multiplied by two ways: dot product and cross product. A dot product gives you stress a scalar quantity. But it's not. How could a scalar quantity could account for both shear and tangential type forces? So it's not. Now, that means stress can also never be a vector as the vector is characterized by only a single direction. But stress could accommodate the two directive forces- normal (which accounts for pressure) and the shear (tangential). So stress is dyadic in nature as it contains two directions and one magnitude. It's a tensor of rank 2. This stress property is made used in electrodynamics by Maxwell in order to write down the Lorentz force acting on a charge in terms of the stress tensor alone which makes the equation neater and well explains everything. The diagonal elements of the electromagnetic stress tensor corresponds to normal forces and the off-diagonal elements correspond to tangential forces. Altogether in three dimensions, we have nine components of the stress tensor. For a detailed study about the revolution made by Maxwell's stress tensor you could refer to Introduction to Electrodynamics by David. J. Griffith.

Comment: So you used mass energy equivalence. But I want to know whether Newtonian waves also have momentum density? I mean, whether the momentum is dependent on special relatively?

Comment: momentum is there always. Special relativity is a way of perception like the Newtonian

Answer (score 0):

From considering the De Broglie Wavelength, $h/mv$, we can show that every wave has momentum if it is considered as a particle derived by its Wavelength.